# How to know when Google show confirm after download Google Drive with field 'webContentLink'

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm working with Google Drive API v3, I use method `files.get` to get a file and download file with field `webContentLink`(https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get)

My button link download look like this:

```
<a href={file.webContentLink} download={file.name}>Download file</a>
```

My problem: when click download button. Sometime It will show a comfirm 'Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses' and replace my website url. I want detect when `webContentLink` after click will show a confirm. If it show confirm, I will add `target="_blank"` to open download in new tab.

I try view field in link reference (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files) to find a boolean field detect that but I still don't know.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76310115/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no option with the Drive API to detect when you will get that message. However, the message `Can't scan file for viruses ... exceeds the maximum file size that Google can scan. This file might harm your computer, so only download this file if you understand the risks.` Appears when you're trying to download a file larger than 100 MB. There is no official documentation where it says about the download file size, but you can find it on several websites. I also tested on my side and got the same result with files larger than 100 MB.

For your request "I want detect when webContentLink after click will show a confirm", you can retrieve the size of a file, that way you know if the file is less than 100 MB then it will download the file without that warning message.

Another thing to consider, you may get different messages when trying to download a file, not necessarily regarding the size of the file. For example, there is another type of message that says:

`This file type might be dangerous ... "NameOfFile" is a file type that might harm your computer. Only download this file if you understand the risks.`

That other message usually happens when trying to download an executable file, like `.exe` files, so you may need to retrieve the `mimeType` of the file too, that way you know if file type is different than `.exe.` it will not show that specific warning.

**Note:** Since you're using the `files.get` method, you can also use it to retrieve the `size` and `mimeType` of the file.

## References:

- [Google Drive Security and Virus Scanning Limits](https://cleandrive.app/file-size-limit-google/#:%7E:text=The%20100%20MB%20limit%20is,files%20larger%20than%20100%20MB.)
- [Metadata for a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files)